# A simple c++ HelloWorld with cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to make my first program with cuda.
So I make this simple HelloWorld with guide of various pages.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void mykernel(void) {
}

int main(void) {
mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
printf("CPU Hello World!\n");
return 0;
}
```

But I am getting this output:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sebastian/Dropbox/Universidad/Trabajo_de_Grado_pregrado/Codigos/HelloWordCuda'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hellowordcuda
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sebastian/Dropbox/Universidad/Trabajo_de_Grado_pregrado/Codigos/HelloWordCuda'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hellowordcuda.o.d"
g++    -c -g -I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hellowordcuda.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hellowordcuda.o hellowordcuda.cpp
hellowordcuda.cpp:19:1: error: ‘__global__’ does not name a type
 __global__ void mykernel(void) {
 ^
hellowordcuda.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hellowordcuda.cpp:24:1: error: ‘mykernel’ was not declared in this scope
 mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
 ^
hellowordcuda.cpp:24:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
 mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
           ^
hellowordcuda.cpp:24:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
 mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
                 ^
hellowordcuda.cpp:24:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
                   ^
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hellowordcuda.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sebastian/Dropbox/Universidad/Trabajo_de_Grado_pregrado/Codigos/HelloWordCuda'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sebastian/Dropbox/Universidad/Trabajo_de_Grado_pregrado/Codigos/HelloWordCuda'
 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I'm sorry for making a question so simple but I just don't find any answer for this.

Thanks a lot, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I used c++ only in college so pardon me if this is a silly question. What is that __global__ keyword? Just saying void mykernel() would also make your method global. __global__ looks like something out of python

Comment: @NSNoob It's part of CUDA.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks Angew!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two things you need to do to make this work:

1. use the CUDA compiler driver `nvcc` to steer compilation of the code
2. rename `hellowordcuda.cpp` to `hellowordcuda.cu` when passing the code to `nvcc`

The second point is necessary because `nvcc` uses the file extension to steer compilation, and if you code has a `.cc` or `.cpp` file extension, it will just pass the code to the host compiler and the same compilation errors will result

Comment: by renaming extension of the file which called .cu file's function to .cu, my problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you're building directly with g++. You need to use NVidia's compiler (nvcc) to use CUDA, and make sure it knows to process the file as CUDA C. This can be achieved by changing the extension to `.cu`, or by playing around with compilation options which specify the file & processing type. I recommend the former.

Comment: Using nvcc will exhibit the same behaviour. The file extension also needs to be changed.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks, incorporated.

Answer (score 4):

In guide also below lines are mentioned,

```
$ nvcc hello.cu
$ a.out
Hello World!
```

Please change `g++` to `nvcc` in your Makefile.

Comment: Same file extension problem applies here to.